# Count all paths in a tree that have cost 0 modulo k

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I have a tree, now I want to count the number of paths going up to the root of the tree, (it need not reach till root node).

While counting the paths, I want to find the cost for that path and do a calculation as (cost % k = 0), to find all such valid paths.

For input k = 2 and list = [1,1,1,1], from = [1,1,4], to = [2,4,3]
List represent cost of every node. from and to represent the edges in the tree.

the tree represented as :

[image]

For the above tree, we have 8 possible paths:

```
1
2
4
2->1
4->1
3
3->4 (this has a path that can reach root node, so this path is considered)
3->4->1
```

But only valid paths are

```
2->1
4->1
3->4
```

that have cost % k = 0. So, the result is 3.

This is my code, here I am checking from and to edges sum and checking if remainder with k is 0, also checking to edges with the remainder as 0.

```
public int findValidPaths(List<Integer> list, int nodes, List<Integer> from, List<Integer> to, int k) {
    int result = 0;
    for(int e : to) {
        if(list.get(e-1) % k == 0) {
            result++;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<from.size(); i++) {
        int cost = list.get(from.get(i)-1) + list.get(to.get(i) -1);
        if(cost%k == 0) {
            result++;
        }
    }
    return result + 1;
}
```

My approach is not correct as I am not checking all paths, how to solve this problem.

**constraints:**

```
cost : 1 to 10^9 
k : 1 to 10^5
```

**Another example:**

Inputs are:

`list = [1,2,2,1,2], from =  [2,2,1,2], to = [3,1,4,5], k = 2`

[image]

The expected output is 6 because valid combinations are:

```
5
3
2
5-2
3-2
4-1
```

Answer (score 4):

A general `O(n)` formulation can be let `f(n)` represent all the remainders that can be reached in prefix sums modulo `k` of traversals down from the root. Then node `n` can be paired with as many of those remainders that are the same as `(sum_head + n) % k`, where `sum_head` is the prefix sum modulo `k` ending at `n`s parent.

In order to use space efficiently, we can use a map of `sum mod k -> count`, recursing down into the tree and unsetting the prefix sum we just created (i.e., backtracking) after the recursion.

For example, `k = 3`

```
            G(2)
        /          \
      E(1)         F(2)
     /    \       /   \
   A(2)  B(4)   C(2)  D(5)
```

Prefix sums modulo `k = 3`:

```
G -> E -> A
2    0    2
       -> B
          1

G -> F -> C
2    1    0
       -> D
          0
```

We arrive at E and count the 0 prefix sum there. At A, we match 2 with the 2 in the `prefix_sum_mod_k` map, which accounts for the path `A -> E`.

We backtrack, unsetting a 2 and examine B, which has no match in the map.

We backtrack to G, unsetting a 1 and a 0, and proceed to F, which has no match. We proceed to C, which is a 0 and count it. We backtrack to F, unsetting a 0, and proceed to D, counting one more 0.

Total: 4

```
E -> G
A -> E
C -> F -> G
D -> F -> G
```

Python code:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def f(k, costs, from_lst, to_lst):
  children = defaultdict(list)

  for i, u in enumerate(from_lst):
    children[u].append(to_lst[i])

  prefixes = defaultdict(int)
  prefixes[0] = 1

  def g(n, s):
    result = 0
    curr = (s + costs[n]) % k
    result += prefixes[curr]
    prefixes[curr] += 1
    for c in children[n]:
      result += g(c, curr)
    prefixes[curr] -= 1
    return result

  return g(0, 0)
```

Output:

```py
params = [
  (3, [2,1,2,2,4,2,5], [0,0,1,1,2,2], [1,2,3,4,5,6]),
  (2, [1,1,1,1], [0,0,3], [1,3,2]),
  (2, [1,2,2,1,2], [0,0,1,1], [1,3,2,4])
]

for args in params:
  print(f(*args), args)

"""
4 (3, [2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 5], [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
3 (2, [1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 3], [1, 3, 2])
6 (2, [1, 2, 2, 1, 2], [0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 3, 2, 4])
"""
```

Java code (assumes the tree root is labeled 1, works for both example inputs):

```java
  private static void directTheGraph(
    Integer node,
    Map<Integer,List<Integer>> children) {
    if (children.containsKey(node)) {
      for (Integer child : children.get(node)) {
        if (children.containsKey(child)) {
          children.get(child).remove(node);
        }
      }
      for (Integer child : children.get(node)) {
        directTheGraph(child, children);
      }
    }
  }

  private static long g(
    Integer node,
    Integer sum,
    List<Integer> costs,
    Map<Integer,Integer> prefixes,
    Map<Integer,List<Integer>> children,
    int k) {
    long result = 0;
    Integer curr = (sum + costs.get(node-1)) % k;
    result += prefixes.getOrDefault(curr, 0);
    if (prefixes.containsKey(curr)) {
      prefixes.put(curr, prefixes.get(curr) + 1);
    } else {
      prefixes.put(curr, 1);
    }
    if (children.containsKey(node)) {
      for (Integer child : children.get(node)) {
        result += g(child, curr, costs, prefixes, children, k);
      }
    }
    prefixes.put(curr, prefixes.get(curr) - 1);
    return result;
  }

  private static long f(
    List<Integer> costs,
    List<Integer> from,
    List<Integer> to,
    int k) {
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> children = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < from.size(); i++) {
      Integer u = from.get(i);
      Integer v = to.get(i);
      if (children.containsKey(u)) {
        children.get(u).add(v);
      } else {
        children.put(u, new ArrayList<>());
        children.get(u).add(v);
      }
      if (children.containsKey(v)) {
        children.get(v).add(u);
      } else {
        children.put(v, new ArrayList<>());
        children.get(v).add(u);
      }
    }

    directTheGraph(1, children);

    Map<Integer, Integer> prefixes = new HashMap<>();
    prefixes.put(0, 1);

    return g(
      1,
      0,
      costs,
      prefixes,
      children,
      k);
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    List<Integer> costs = List.of(1,1,1,1);
    List<Integer> from = List.of(1,1,4);
    List<Integer> to = List.of(2,4,3);
    int k = 2;

    System.out.println(f(costs, from, to, k));

    costs = List.of(1,2,2,1,2);
    from = List.of(2,2,1,2);
    to = List.of(3,1,4,5);
    k = 2;

    System.out.println(f(costs, from, to, k));
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried reading this answer several times, but I am not getting it clearly. can you please share pseudo code as well for this approach.

Comment: I am trying with input `(2, [1,2,2,1,2], [2,2,1,2], [3,1,4,5])` I am getting output as 0 with this answer, but the expected output is 6. Because for this case the valid combinations are : 4-1, 2-1, 3-2, 5-2, 5, 3 so total 6 combinations are possible. Can you please check this case.

Comment: I have added the graph under the Another example section in my post. Please check.

Comment: @learner I added your example in my code. It works fine. Sorry, one more constraint about the input to the function (in addition to zero-based) is that to and from must be in the direction away from the root. See how I composed the arguments.

Comment: Got it, but my test case has values as `(2, [1,2,2,1,2], [2,2,1,2], [3,1,4,5])`, so as zero based I am changing that to `(2, [1,2,2,1,2], [1,1,0,1], [2,0,3,4])`. But direction I cannot change here as my test case format itself is like this. Is there a way to solve this kind of input

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try that. What is the time complexity of this solution and also the algorithm approach used to solve this problem. Can you please help me with those details.

Comment: @learner sure -- the time complexity is `O(n)` since we visit each node once. If `n ≤ k`, which you indicated it is, then I believe the space complexity is also `O(n)` since at most `n` remainders would be mapped. I think we can call this approach both backtracking and dynamic programming.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, your second example has incorrect values for variable `from` since there is no path from the root (node 1) to any other node (i.e. the value 1 is not present in variable `from`).

If I understand your question correctly, you need to total path costs bottom up, i.e. starting with leaf nodes and working your way up to the root. This is a bit more complicated then computing total costs from the root to the leaves.

The solution requires that for each node we first compute its parent (I have renumbered every node to be origin-0 in the `parent` list). This is an O(N) operation. This allows us to walk the tree from leaf nodes up to the root accumulating costs as we go along. It is true that some nodes (those with two children) will be visited twice, but this is still an O(N) operation since the worst case the number of nodes visited will be < 2*N.

```Java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Test {
    public int findValidPaths(int[] list, int[] from, int[] to, int k) {
        // Convert passed arguments into a tree:
        // Find leaves:
        HashSet<Integer> leaves = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i: to)
            leaves.add(i - 1); // 0-origin
        HashSet<Integer> fromSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i: from)
            fromSet.add(i - 1); // 0-origin
        leaves.removeAll(fromSet);
        int numNodes = list.length;
        int[] parent = new int[numNodes];
        parent[0] = -1; // root node has no parent
        for (int i = 0; i < from.length; i++) {
            int fromNode = from[i] - 1; // 0-origin
            int toNode = to[i] - 1; // 0-origin
            parent[toNode] = fromNode;
        }
        int counter = 0;
        int nodesVisited = 0;
        for (int nodeNumber: leaves) {
            int totalCost = 0;
            while (nodeNumber != -1) {
                nodesVisited += 1;
                totalCost += list[nodeNumber];
                if (totalCost % k == 0)
                    counter += 1;
                nodeNumber = parent[nodeNumber];
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("Total nodes: %d, Nodes visited: %d\n", numNodes, nodesVisited);
        return counter;
    }

    public void test1() {
        int[] list = {1, 1, 1, 1};
        int[] from = {1, 1, 4};
        int[] to = {2, 4, 3};
        int n = findValidPaths(list, from, to, 2);
        System.out.printf("Number of paths: %d\n", n);
    }

    public void test2() {
        int[] list = {1,2,2,1,2};
        int[] from = {1,1,2,2};
        int[] to = {2,4,3,5};
        int n = findValidPaths(list, from, to, 2);
        System.out.printf("Number of paths: %d\n", n);
    }

    public void test3() {
        /*
                    1
                  /
                2
              /
            2
        */
        int[] list = {1,2,2};
        int[] from = {1,2};
        int[] to = {2,3};
        int n = findValidPaths(list, from, to, 2);
        System.out.printf("Number of paths: %d\n", n);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.test1();
        test.test2();
        test.test3();
    }

}
```

Prints:

```None
Total nodes: 4, Nodes visited: 5
Number of paths: 2
Total nodes: 5, Nodes visited: 8
Number of paths: 5
Total nodes: 3, Nodes visited: 3
Number of paths: 2
```

Comment: Walking from leaves to root while attempting to calculate paths that are subsections of the whole path from the leaf to the root and have cost 0 mod k, as the problem requests, would have exponential complexity, as I understand it. Could you please describe in words how your algorithm achieves that while walking from leaves to root?

Comment: (OP clarified in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72859836/count-all-paths-in-a-tree-that-have-cost-0-modulo-k#comment128710227_72859836) that valid paths for counting include paths in the middle of the tree.)

Comment: Let's look at the second, more efficient algorithm. Finding the predecessor of each node (code is the loop beginning with `for (int i = 0; i < from.length; i++) {` ) is O(N) since its body is O(1). Then `walktree` recursively visits every node once starting with leaf nodes and that is clearly O(N).

Comment: In a tree, by definition, many nodes share predecessors. I don't see how walking up recursively from leaves can prevent visiting nodes more than once.

Comment: Also, does this algorithm count valid paths that don't start nor end at a leaf or root?

Comment: Well I think the OP should have updated the question body itself since if that is the case I  obviously missed it. And wouldn't it then follow that one could start from the root and work your way down to leaves if that is the case and therefore the first sentence of the problem description, i.e. **I have a tree, now I want to count the number of paths going up to the root of the tree, (it need not reach till root node).** is totally misleading?

Comment: Yes, I agree that the description could be a lot clearer :) That's probably why the comments include many clarifications.

Comment: I am sorry you don't see that in a tree each node has at most one predecessor (the root has none). So each time we recurse we are processing a single node.

Comment: I'm confused -- is "predecessors" in your post, what is commonly referred to as "children" in descriptions about tree graphs? If so, then I misunderstood and take it back.

Comment: No. "predecessors" are parents and each child has only one in a *tree* (as opposed to a more general *graph*).

Comment: If predecessors are parents, then I don't take back my confusion :) If we have parent A with children B and C, and we iterate on B and C, visiting their predecessors, A gets visited twice, no?

Comment: I have updated the answer to provide just one solution (the more efficient one), simplifying the code since a node can only have one parent and I can therefore use a simpler structure. The complexity is still O(N) as I have explained in my answer.

Comment: If we visit all paths from leaves to root, we would visit nodes between `average_num_children` and `num_leaves` times. Clearly, the root would be visited `num_leaves` times.

Comment: But we could have an O(n) method that calculates what your function does by adapting the method I posted to only add to the result when we're on a leaf node.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to turn the tree upside-down and view it as a DAG (directed acyclic graph), meaning the links go from child to parent. We introduce a source node with links to all other nodes. The links between the source and any other node are a path.

To find all valid paths, we recursively traverse the DAG starting at the source node. At each node, we determine whether it is a valid path using the validity formula with the cost accumulated along the path up to that node. The recursion rewinds at the former root node.

If we count the number of valid paths as the recursion proceeds down, we can sum the counts from the different branches when it rewinds, ending up with the total when it finishes.

Once you have the DAG, this should be just a few lines of Java code.

---

I added a Java implementation using the DAG approach. I made it recursive first, but it seems Java does not optimize tail recursion, so I switched to iteration. I use only ints and int arrays to avoid time-consuming type-coercion between int and Integer. The code is as fast as it gets in Java, reminiscent of C.

The complexity of the average height of a random binary tree with N nodes is O(logN) with high probability. If we use that as an upper bound for the average path length, the DAG approach becomes O(N*logN). The DAG approach is suitable for parallel execution, which makes complexity drop to O(logN). In practice, we do not have N processors, but the code becomes faster also with fewer.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class CountPaths {

    CountPaths(int K, int[] list, int[] from, int[] to) { // constructor
        N = list.length + 1;
        this.K = K;
        dag = new int[N];
        cost = new int[N];
        for (int i=0; i<list.length; i++) cost[i+1] = list[i]; // setup costs
        for (int i=0; i<to.length; i++) dag[to[i]] = from[i]; // setup DAG
        path = new int[N]; // the current path
        top = 0; // top of path
    }

    void go() {    // start
        System.out.println("K = " + K);
        System.out.println("Cost = " + Arrays.toString(cost));
        System.out.println("Dag = " + Arrays.toString(dag));
        System.out.println("---");
        int n = 0; // valid paths
        for (int i=1; i<N; i++) { // all paths
            top = 0;
            n += nodes(i, 0);
            System.out.println("---");
        }
        System.out.println("Valid paths = " + n);
    }

    final int N, K;
    final int[] dag, cost;
    int[] path;
    int top;

    boolean validity(int cost, int K) { // check validity
        return (cost % K) == 0;
    }

    int nodes(int curNode, int accCost) { // iterative processing of nodes
        int n = 0; // number of valid paths
        while (curNode > 0) {
            path[top++] = curNode; // update current path
            accCost += cost[curNode]; // accumulated cost
            boolean valid = validity(accCost, K); // check validity
            if (valid) n++;
            
            System.out.print("Path=" + path[0]);
            for (int i=1; i<top; i++) System.out.print("->" + path[i]);
            System.out.print(", Cost=" + accCost);
            if (valid) System.out.print(", (Valid)");
            System.out.println();
            
            curNode = dag[curNode]; // next node in path
        }
        return n;
    }

/*
    int nodes(int curNode, int accCost) { // recursive processing of nodes
        if (curNode == 0) return 0; // stop criterion
        path[top++] = curNode; // update current path
        accCost += cost[curNode];    // accumulated cost
        boolean valid = validity(accCost, K); // check validity

        System.out.print("Path=" + path[0]);
        for (int i=1; i<top; i++) System.out.print("->" + path[i]);
        System.out.print(", Cost=" + accCost);
        if (valid) System.out.print(", (Valid)");
        System.out.println();

        return (valid ? 1 : 0) + nodes(dag[curNode], accCost); // tail recursive call to next node in path
    }
*/  
    
} // CountPaths

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int K=2;
        int[] list = {1,1,1,1};
        int[] from = {1,1,4};
        int[] to = {2,4,3};

/*        int K=2;
        int[] list = {1,2,2,1,2};
        int[] from = {2,1,1,2}; // corrected [2,2,1,2] in the example
        int[] to = {3,2,4,5}; // corrected [3,1,4,5] in the example
*/
        new CountPaths(K, list, from, to).go(); // Construct CountPaths and call go
    }

} // Main
```

And here is the result of the two test runs:

```
   1.
    
    K = 2
    Cost = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    Dag = [0, 0, 1, 4, 1]
    ---
    Path=1, Cost=1
    ---
    Path=2, Cost=1
    Path=2->1, Cost=2, (Valid)
    ---
    Path=3, Cost=1
    Path=3->4, Cost=2, (Valid)
    Path=3->4->1, Cost=3
    ---
    Path=4, Cost=1
    Path=4->1, Cost=2, (Valid)
    ---
    Valid paths = 3
    
    
    2.
    
    K = 2
    Cost = [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2]
    Dag = [0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2]
    ---
    Path=1, Cost=1
    ---
    Path=2, Cost=2, (Valid)
    Path=2->1, Cost=3
    ---
    Path=3, Cost=2, (Valid)
    Path=3->2, Cost=4, (Valid)
    Path=3->2->1, Cost=5
    ---
    Path=4, Cost=1
    Path=4->1, Cost=2, (Valid)
    ---
    Path=5, Cost=2, (Valid)
    Path=5->2, Cost=4, (Valid)
    Path=5->2->1, Cost=5
    ---
    Valid paths = 6
```

Comment: Added Java code